# Eclipse CDT Build Output Parser to work with Microsoft compiler (cl.exe)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, build, cl

Currently *CDT GCC Build Output Parser* Identifies build log to auto configure Paths and symbols in an Eclipse CDT project when you use GCC as compiler. It detects -I and -D for includes and defines passed to the compiler command. **Is there a way to configure this Build Output Parser to work with the output of Microsoft Visual C compiler cl.exe as cl uses /I and /D instead GCC arguments.**

Comment: Of course there is. Many cross-platform/compiler build systems deal with that. Two examples are `SCons` and `CMake`.

Answer (score 0):

Well after some research I couldnt find the way to configure the Output parser to identify cl syntax. The quickest solution was to make a python script that modifies cl build log to look like gcc log and set it in Eclipse as the build command.